# Count rows and columns for multiple CSV files and make new file

Tags: awk

I have multiple large *comma separated* CSV files in a directory. But, as a toy example:

- `one.csv` has 3 rows, 2 columns
- `two.csv` has 4 rows 5 columns

This is what the files look like -

```
# one.csv
  a b 
1 1 3
2 2 2
3 3 1

# two.csv
  c d e f g
1 4 1 1 4 1
2 3 2 2 3 2
3 2 3 3 2 3
4 1 4 4 1 4
```

The goal is to make a new `.txt` or `.csv` that gives the rows and columns for each:

```
one 3 2  
two 4 5
```

To get the rows and columns (and dump it into a file) for a single file

```
$ awk -F "," '{print NF}' *.csv | sort | uniq -c > dims.txt
```

But I'm not understanding the syntax to get counts for multiple files.

###### What I've tried

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=2; i++) -F "," '{print NF}' *.csv$i | sort | uniq -c}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gnu awk you can do this in a single `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, 'ENDFILE {
   print gensub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", "1", FILENAME), FNR-1, NF-1
}' one.csv two.csv > dims.txt

cat dims.txt

one 3 2
two 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

With any `awk`, you could try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(cols && rows){
    print file,rows,cols
  }
  rows=cols=file=""
  file=FILENAME
  sub(/\..*/,"",file)
  cols=NF
  next
}
{
  rows=(FNR-1)
}
END{
  if(cols && rows){
    print file,rows,cols
  }
}
' one.csv two.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                     ##Checking condition if this is first line of each line then do following.
  if(cols && rows){         ##Checking if cols AND rows are NOT NULL then do following.
    print file,rows,cols    ##Printing file, rows and cols variables here.
  }
  rows=cols=file=""         ##Nullifying rows, cols and file here.
  file=FILENAME             ##Setting FILENAME value to file here.
  sub(/\..*/,"",file)       ##Removing everything from dot to till end of value in file.
  cols=NF                   ##Setting NF values to cols here.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  rows=(FNR-1)              ##Setting FNR-1 value to rows here.
}
END{                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(cols && rows){         ##Checking if cols AND rows are NOT NULL then do following.
    print file,rows,cols    ##Printing file, rows and cols variables here.
  }
}
' one.csv two.csv           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over all CSVs print the name for each file and the dimensions

```
for i in *.csv; do awk -F "," 'END{print FILENAME, NR, NF}' $i; done > dims.txt
```

If you want to avoid `awk` you can also do it `wc -l` for lines and  `grep -o "CSV-separator" | wc -l` for fields

Comment: once for each file, do you need the sum for all?

Comment: @DonaldSeinen is because i din't use -F, corrected now

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK`'s [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) for this task as follows, let content of `one.csv` be

```
1,3
2,2
3,1
```

and `two.csv` be

```
4,1,1,4,1
3,2,2,3,2
2,3,3,2,3
1,4,4,1,4
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}ENDFILE{print FILENAME, FNR, NF}' one.csv two.csv
```

output

```
one.csv 3 2
two.csv 4 5
```

Explanation: `ENDFILE` is executed after processing every file, I set `FS` to `,` assuming that fields are `,`-separated and there is not `,` inside filed, `FILENAME`, `FNR`, `NF` are built-in GNU `AWK` variables: `FNR` is number of current row in file, i.e. in `ENDFILE` number of last row, `NF` is number of fileds (again of last row). If you have files with headers use `FNR-1`,  if you have rows prepended with row number use `NF-1`.

*edit: changed NR to FNR*

Comment: [I had similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70153618/548225) And `7,5` is not OP's expected output and `.csv` is also not in OP's output.

Comment: You should be printing FNR-1 instead of NR and NF-1 instead of NF given the OPs posted sample input.

Answer (score 1):

Without GNU awk you can use the shell plus POSIX awk this way:

```
for fn in *.csv; do
    cols=$(awk '{print NF; exit}' "$fn")
    rows=$(awk 'END{print NR-1}' "$fn")
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "${fn%.csv}" "$rows" "$cols" 
done
```

Prints:

```
one 3 2
two 4 5
```